# HTML Array script not working (in_Array not defined)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

TL;DR Need help on making this script work

Hi, I've been trying to get this script working with an array structure but it doesn't work and I keep getting the error in_Array not defined. If possible can anyone point out the mistakes I am making even if it minimal. Thanks for your time -Simon

```
<script>
$traffictick = Array("OFF","ON","OFF");

function tick() {
  if (in_Array("ON", $traffictick[1])) {
    yellowon();
    console.log("Yellow");
    $traffictick = Array("OFF,OFF,ON;");
  } else if (in_Array("ON", $traffictick[2])) {
    redon();
     console.log("Red");
    $traffictick = Array("OFF,ON,ON;");

  } else if (in_Array("ON", $traffictick[2])) {
    yellowon();
     console.log("Red & Yellow");
    $traffictick = Array("ON,OFF,OFF;");

  } else if (in_Array("ON", $traffictick[1] & $trafficktick[2])) {
    greenon();
    console.log("Green");
    $traffictick = Array("OFF,ON,OFF;");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you create the `in_Array` function?

Comment: Are you conflating PHP and Javascript…?

Comment: maybe you meant to use $.inArray the jquery function there is no in_Array pre-defined function in js

Comment: Yes, I tried to make it check the position of the array to see whether it should go on or off
EDIT: I've used online resources to write this and it was supposed to be written in javascript & html

Comment: → https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score -2):

there is no in_array function in javascript, you have to check manually that your value exist in array or not,

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use this function instead of in_array and also you are passing value as a second parameter, you must pass an array.

Comment: What, Javascript arrays contain no methods at all to [test membership](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessor_methods)?!  Call Brendan Eich!

Comment: i am saying there is no in_array function, I didn't say there isnt any other method to check membership @deceze

Comment: @deceze there is indexOf

Comment: So why are you reimplementing `inArray` instead of pointing OP towards existing methods? Even if you insist on implementing a function called `inArray`, at least implement it like `return haystack.indexOf(needle) !== -1`.

Comment: @www0z0k Sorry, forgot the `</sarcasm>` tag.

Comment: there are multiple ways to do one thing, this function returns the expected result, I think its valid to use @deceze